# Why is the "code" the same as the "name"?

Tags: c, pointers

The giraffe's name and code are to be modified by the user after printing out once. I am entering different values for each of these, yet the "code" is the same as the "name."

I believe I know how to **work around** this error, but I'd like to know how to solve this problem without making too many modifications or additions to my code. I figure it's my usage of pointers, as this is the first time I've come in contact with them.

### Take a look:

```
typedef struct {

  int age;
  double height;
  char *name;

}giraffe;

void renameGiraffe(giraffe *g, char *na){

  g->name = na;

}

void recodeGiraffe(char * codes[], int n, char * code){

  codes[n] = code;

}


int main()
{
  giraffe north; giraffe south; giraffe west;
  north.name = "Fred";
  south.name = "Bill";
  west.name = "Kate";

  char in1[] = "";
  giraffe* exhibit[] = {&north, &south, &west};
  char* codes[] = {"GN","GS","GW"};

  for(int i = 0; i < (sizeof(exhibit)/sizeof(exhibit[0])); i++)
  {
    printf("The giraffe named %s has the code %s\n", exhibit[i]->name, codes[i]);
  }

  printf("Let's recode a giraffe. Which giraffe would you like to recode?\n\n");
  scanf("%s", in1);

  if(strcmp("north", in1)== 0)
  {
    printf("what is the new code for north?\n");
    scanf("%s", in1);
    recodeGiraffe(codes, 0, in1);
    printf("North has been recoded. The new code for north is %s\n", in1);
  }

  printf("Let's rename the north giraffe. What's the new name?\n");
  scanf("%s",in1);
  renameGiraffe(&north, in1);

printf("Reprinting the list of giraffes now:\n\n");

for(int i = 0; i < (sizeof(exhibit)/sizeof(exhibit[0])); i++)
  {
    printf("The giraffe named %s has the code %s\n", exhibit[i]->name, codes[i]);
  }

  return 0;
}
```

My output:

```
The giraffe named Fred has the code GN // Ignore the other two giraffes.
The giraffe named Bill has the code GS
The giraffe named Kate has the code GW
Let's recode a giraffe. Which giraffe would you like to recode?

north

What is the new code for north?

NOR

North has been recoded. The new code for north is NOR

Let's rename the north giraffe. What's the new name?

FREDDY

Reprinting the list of giraffes now:

The giraffe named FREDDY has the code FREDDY //The code should be NOR. 
The giraffe named Bill has the code GS
The giraffe named Kate has the code GW
```

Comment: `char in1[] = "";` creates an array with room for exactly one byte. Try `char in1[100] = "";`

Comment: `char in1[] = ""; /*...*/   scanf("%s", in1);` You're letting your user write a string of indefinite length into a place in your program's memory where you have place for just one byte, thereby allowing/inviting them to completely mess up your program.

Comment: @PSkocik I just starting learning C today. I wish I had a book to consult.  ```char in1[100] = "";``` Makes no difference in my output.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're reading the new name into `in1` then assigning the `name` field,  which is a pointer, to point to `in1`.  You then read the code into `n1`, which is what the `name` field is pointing to, so `name` has changed.

Rather than using pointers for `name` and `codes`, use arrays big enough to hold any expected string, then read directly into those strings.

```
typedef struct {

  int age;
  double height;
  char name[100];

}giraffe;

int main()
{
  giraffe north; giraffe south; giraffe west;
  strcpy(north.name, "Fred");
  strcpy(south.name, "Bill");
  strcpy(west.name, "Kate");

  char in1[100] = "";
  giraffe* exhibit[] = {&north, &south, &west};
  char codes[][100] = {"GN","GS","GW"};

  for(int i = 0; i < (sizeof(exhibit)/sizeof(exhibit[0])); i++)
  {
    printf("The giraffe named %s has the code %s\n", exhibit[i]->name, codes[i]);
  }

  printf("Let's recode a giraffe. Which giraffe would you like to recode?\n\n");
  scanf("%s", in1);

  if(strcmp("north", in1)== 0)
  {
    printf("what is the new code for north?\n");
    scanf("%s", codes[0]);
    printf("North has been recoded. The new code for north is %s\n", codes[0]));
  }

  printf("Let's rename the north giraffe. What's the new name?\n");
  scanf("%s",north.name);

  printf("Reprinting the list of giraffes now:\n\n");

  for(int i = 0; i < (sizeof(exhibit)/sizeof(exhibit[0])); i++)
  {
    printf("The giraffe named %s has the code %s\n", exhibit[i]->name, codes[i]);
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: That's one way to do it, but really the "right" way is to leave the structure members as pointers, allocate exactly the right amount of memory for them after input, and copy the input data over.

Comment: @LeeDanielCrocker Ideally yes, however given OP's level of experience it's probably best not the throw dynamic memory management at them just yet.